# Flex 4 cursor (special hit area)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, cursors, flex4

How I can make a cursor with an image, but the mouse click area must be at the center of the image

In addition, if any way to change the img size this will be great

Answer (score 0):

If you have Flash, you can prepare a centered symbol and export it in a swf. Then, you have to embed this swf in Flex with Embed metatag. You can use this in your custom cursor. I'm not sure what you meant with changing the size though.